# How to disable chrome from prefixing all links with "https://www.google.com/url?q="

Tags: google-chrome

I see this behavior with links in gmail messages as well as links in google sheets.  When I copy and paste the link URL into a new tab, chrome goes straight there.  But if I click the link, the new tab/window opens and goes to "https://www.google.com/url?q=" + the link URL.

When I try the same google sheet in firefox, I go straight to the link URL, so I'm assuming that this is some sort of chrome behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this [open-source](https://github.com/newhouse/url-tracking-stripper) plugin:
[URL Tracking Stripper & Redirect Skipper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-tracking-stripper-red/flnagcobkfofedknnnmofijmmkbgfamf/overview?hl=en)

I tried and on Chrome it works! Thanks for your question - I found the solution because of your detailed description.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I have been looking for!.  thank you

Comment: @swv, if answer solves your question be so kind at accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately, like many of the other reviews stated, that extension doesn't seem to do anything, at least not for me.